# How to ask OP a question rather than provide answer as new user

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

How do I ask the OP a question?  I have just signed up and wanted the OP to clarify a question they had.  However the only option was to "Answer Question"

*edit

Thanks for answering this for me.  I thought I was going crazy.  I answered some question and someone was saying to turn it into a question.  *shrug*

Thanks

Comment: Earn 50 reputation and then you can comment on the question asking for clarification. Until then, I'm afraid you have to skip such questions.

Comment: +1 for asking here rather than clicking "Answer Question" and writing "I know this isn't an answer...", as many newcomers do. Welcome to the site.

Comment: @user2270470, Welcome to [SO]; you seem like a responsible type, so *please* be sure to contribute. The community always needs more good people.

Comment: Thanks all for the answer.  I love this place so far.  I love sharing what little knowledge I have and learning new stuff as well.

Answer (score 17):

You will have to wait till you get 50 reputation points. After that you can comment on the post.

See: [Comment everywhere privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)

> Reputation Required 50

Comment: What would happen if we killed that restriction? I'm aware there could some spam posts, but I don't think that's something the current moderation system cannot handle.

Comment: "Could"? We'd be flooded. There are no quality restrictions on comments as there are on questions and answers.

Comment: @J.Steen did spam comments actually use to be a problem back in the day?

Comment: I wonder if lowering the threshold from 50 to 10 or 20 would cause any problems. Rephrase: I wonder how many problems it would cause, and whether the benefit would be worth it.

Comment: @SamIam Probably? Any way scumbags can spam, they will.

Comment: @J.Steen "Probably?" you say?  It seems like you haven't actually seen the problem before.  I bring it up because It's not a given that we'll get an unmanageable amount of spam; especially considering the second-class status we give to comments around here.  Even Youtube comments, which supposedly has a "high level" of spam tends to appear to be 90% human-written comments.

Comment: @SamIam I'm very glad you still have faith in humanity, and that's not sarcasm, trust me. And no. In comments on the SE network, I haven't seen the problem. Possibly due to the restriction of 50 rep. Possibly due to spammers being unaware of this goldmine of an opportunity. Though I do doubt the latter. =)

Comment: @SamIam Perhaps a provisional period of reducing the required rep to 1 could be instituted on a smaller site, to see if it's exploited, and to see what kind of comments we get.

Comment: I think a limit of more like 20 (which would make it difficult to use for spam, but easier for a newcomer to catch up) would be reasonable.